# Error form is undefined in meteor App

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

**JS File: -**

```
result=[];
Meteor.call('getApiResult', function (err, res) {
    if (res) {
        console.log("reached meteor call")
        console.log(res);
        result=res;

    }
});
Template.dpVar.events = {
        'submit .add-product-form' : function  (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault(); //prevent form to change URL
            var form = evt.target; //this is the .add-product-form element
            console.log("testing", form);
            console.log(result);
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var tempName = result[i];
                console.log("form[tempName] is ");
                console.log(form[tempName]);


               // var tempVal = form[tempName].value
               // console.log("temp name is ", tempName);

              //  productDB.insert({ tempName: tempVal });
              //  console.log("temp val is ", tempVal);
            }
        }
    }
```

**HTML File :-**

```
<template name="dpVar">
    <h1>variants</h1>

    <!-- here is our form -->
    <form class="add-product-form">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
            <tbody>
            {{#each variant}}
            {{#each VARIENTS}}
            {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "Text"}}
            <tr>
                <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="variables" name="{{this.NAME}}" value={{this.NAME}}>
                </td>

            </tr>
            {{/if}}

            {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "price"}}
            <tr>
                <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="{{this.NAME}}" value={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
            {{/if}}

            {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "color"}}
            <tr>
                <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <select name={{this.NAME}}>
                            <option>Color</option>
                            <option value="Green">Green</option>
                            <option value="White">White</option>
                            <option value="Red">Red</option>
                            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/if}}

            {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "boolean"}}
            <tr>
                <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
            {{/if}}

            {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "checkbox"}}
            <tr>
                <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "string"}}
            <tr>
                <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "date"}}
            <tr>
                <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
                <td><input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" name={{this.NAME}}></td>
            </tr>
            {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- here I added type="submit" for button, so it submits the form -->
        <button class="btn btn-success addproduct" id="CreateNewProduct" type="submit">Create new product</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

**Error:**

> Form[tempName] is undefined

What Am I doing wrong?

I have changed the submit event to this

```
 Template.dpVar.events = {
        'submit .add-product-form' : function  (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault(); //prevent form to change URL
            var form = evt.target; //this is the .add-product-form element
            console.log("testing", form);
            console.log(result);
            data = {};
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var tempName = result[i];
                if (form[tempName] !== void 0) {
                    var tempVal = form[tempName].value;
                    console.log("temp name is ", tempName);
                    data[tempName] = tempVal;
                    console.log("temp val is ", tempVal);
                }
            }
            productDB.insert(data);
        }
    }
```

but I am not able to create entries inside the DB.

```
{ "_id" : "urkfA4ozF4dFZihSX" }
{ "_id" : "Q8nu9eXQLPnPQSPo7" }
```

This DB is being created currently

I want it to be {"Brand" : Lee, "Price" : 11} etc assuming result was [Brand,Price] and its values are taken up from UI

Comment: In your code, you are iterating on an undefined `result` variable... What is `result`?

Comment: Are you sure this is your code exactly as is? You should be getting `result is undefined.` as an error if it is

Comment: updating the question for result

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense... How can you get `Form[tempName] is undefined` when there is no reference to `Form[tempName]` in the code? Or should it be `form[tempName] is undefined`? The line `Template.dpVar.events = { ...` is incorrect. It should be a function call - e.g. `Template.dpVar.events({'submit .add-product-form' : function  (evt) {...}});` Posting the exact console output would be helpful.

Comment: updating the add product form